# MongoDB aggregation $lookup pipeline convert from array of objects to flat array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this

```
progresses = [ {owner: 123, prop: 111 }, {owner: 123, prop: 222 } ... ];
```

Aggregation framework.

```
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'progresses',
        pipeline: [{ $match: { owner: ObjectId(userId) } }],
        as: 'progress',
      },
    },
```

Is it possible to add one more pipeline stage to `lookup` to convert to flat array just with `prop`?

```
[ {owner: 123, prop: 111 }, {owner: 123, prop: 222 } ... ] --> [111, 222]
```

Comment: Just add `{ "$addFields": { "progress": "$progress.prop" }}`